# iOS UISearchBar not showing keyboard on first tap

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, keyboard, uisearchbar

I have a view controller with a UISearchBar at the top and it takes two or three taps before the keyboard shows up. It does this on simulator and on device. Anyone knows what is causing this? I sometimes have this issue with UITextField too?

Thanks,

I'm developing for iPad and using Xcode 4.5 and deploying for iOS 5.0 and +

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is it that you are searching, but if it is in UITableView, you could use UISearchDisplayController - Sample [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848) - makes it a lot easier to deal with table search.

Comment: Well I have a custom grid view, so I am not using a UITableView and am not using a UISearchDisplayController.